# SlateJS Toolbar Using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, slatejs

I am trying to set up a toolbar on slate using React Hooks.  Something seems to be going wrong, and I can't figure out what.  Here is my code:

```
const renderMark = (props, editor, next) => {
  const { children, mark, attributes } = props
  switch (mark.type) {
    case "bold":
      return <strong {...attributes}>{children}</strong>
    case "italic":
      return <i {...attributes}>{children}</i>
    case "underline":
      return <u {...attributes}>{children}</u>
    default:
      return next()
  }
}

const onClickMark = (event, type, editor) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  editor.toggleMark(type)
}


<>
      <Toolbar>
        <Button onPointerDown={event => onClickMark(event, "bold")}>
          <BoldIcon />
        </Button>
        <Button onPointerDown={event => onClickMark(event, "italic")}>
          <ItalicIcon />
        </Button>
        <Button onPointerDown={event => onClickMark(event, "underline")}>
          <UnderlineIcon />
        </Button>
      </Toolbar>

      <Editor
        onChange={handleChange}
        onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
        renderMark={renderMark}
        renderNode={renderNode}
        value={value}
      />
    </>
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I needed to bind the toolbar to the editor.  I did that using the `useRef` hook as follows.

```
const editorRef = useRef()

const onClickMark = (event, type, editorRef) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  editorRef.current.toggleMark(type)
}

  return (
    <>
      <Toolbar>
        <Button onPointerDown={event => onClickMark(event, "bold", editorRef)}>
          <BoldIcon />
        </Button>
        ...
      </Toolbar>

      <StyledEditor
        ...
        ref={editorRef}
        ...
      />
    </>
```